# Need help to get Array in Linq from List of Objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-3.0, angular-fullstack

I have following list of volsExpiry....I need all expiries group by VolNames.
And I need separate Exipiries in an Array format. Please help. Thank you!

```cs
var volsExpiry = from vol in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                 select new
                 {
                    VolName = vol.Field<string>("VolName"),
                    Expiry = vol.Field<Single>("Expiry")
                  };

var expiresByVols1 = from b in volsExpiry
                     group b by b.VolName into d
                     select d;

foreach (var item in expiresByVols1)
{
    var allExpiries = from c in expiresByVols1
                      where c.Key == item.Key
                      select c;
}
```

Comment: What would be the expected output type? `Dictionary<string, Single[]>`?

Comment: @PeterCsala thanks for your reply...actually I need allExpiries as an array.

Comment: Okay. How do you want store the groups?